# Thread safe next number (or round-robin) service in linux

Tags: shell-script, parallelism, multithreading, round-robin

I have an Ubuntu machine and a scenario in which I need to generate the next number (starting from X) between 0 and 20 in a round-robin way.

I need a way to get the next number which will be thread safe, some sort of script (maybe?) which provide me the "next-number" in a round-robin way.

It is very easy to write a script which saves a value into the filesystem, and every time someone asks for the next number, it will increment and save it again.

The problem is, this is not thread safe, and will not provide a real round-robin scenario. I am assuming the script might be called in parallel which might destroy the file.

Also, writing to a file seems very slow scenario...(I can live with that, if this is the only way)

Does anyone know on some other way to do that?

Comment: Some ideas: use file locks, files should not be slow if cached; Use a sequential process to do the counting and to launch parallel processes to do the work (this will work if a process will run to completion, and can know its number at the start.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sem` from GNU Parallel:

```
sem --id givenum give-next-number-program
```